# UILocalNotification doesn't fire in didEnterRegion

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have implemented the

> didEnterRegion

method and it works in background for example if I show an alertview...even with the app in background (when I foreground the app the alertViews show)
I use alertview only to test the didEnterRegion method in background and it works...but now i`m trying to fire an UILocalNotification in didEnterRegion but the UILocalNotification is not firing. There`s my code:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    int iRegiao = [region.identifier intValue];
    Location *ocorrencia = (Location *)[self.locations.objects objectAtIndex:iRegiao];
  //  NSLog(@"Voce está proximo da %@", ocorrencia.name);
    // UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];// Now here you can manage the fire time.
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.alertBody = ocorrencia.name;
    notification.alertAction = ocorrencia.name;
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not firing? If your app is in the foreground, then instead of showing a notification alert view your app delegate's `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method will be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use `- (void)presentLocalNotificationNow:(UILocalNotification *)notification` on `UIApplication`? (it ignores `fireDate`)

Comment: `[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:notification] ` instead of `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];`  ?  yes..and doesn't fire too

Comment: Are you running iOS 8.0? If so, you must call the `registerUserNotificationSettings:` method to let the system know what types of alerts, if any, you plan to display to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Are you targeting iOS 8? If so, you need to ask for permission for local notifications.

Try this:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge categories:nil]];
}
```

The `respondsToSelector:` check is needed if you are also supporting iOS 7 or below.